# How can I properly execute this javascript within my php statement?

Tags: javascript, php, session

The following code will only be called when a session has timed out. I basically want to display a confirm dialog with javascript to make the user pick if he wants to remain online or not. My problem is that the php that closes the session inside the javascript seems to be executed even if the confirm is true.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_SESSION['last_activity']) && (time() - $_SESSION['last_activity'] > 5)) {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    if (confirm("You were logged off due to inactivity, if you would like to remain logged in click OK.")) {
        header("Location:/");
    } else {
    <?php
    connect();
    if(!connect()) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        header( "refresh:3; url=/index.php" );
    }
    mysql_select_db('www');
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET online='0'
    WHERE username='$user'");
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    ?>
    }
    </script>
<?php
}
$_SESSION['last_activity'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
?>
```

Comment: Move your php code in else part to a PHP file and send either an ajax call to it or redirect to it via window.location. The problem is mentioned by @rightfold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP code is run *before* the page is loaded by the browser. JavaScript is run *after* the page is loaded by the browser. You cannot just mix them like this and expect everything to somehow happily work. See [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [WebSockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

Comment: The wiki answers didn't help budd :\ Thank you though